# How can I reduce the length of my conditionals in my JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, react-native, if-statement

```
let getSlotList = [];
    if (
      res.data.hasOwnProperty('alley') &&
      res.data.hasOwnProperty('booked') &&
      res.data.hasOwnProperty('reminder')
    ) {
      getSlotList = [
        ...res.data.alley,
        ...res.data.booked,
        ...res.data.reminder,
      ];
    } else if (
      res.data.hasOwnProperty('alley') &&
      res.data.hasOwnProperty('booked')
    ) {
      getSlotList = [...res.data.alley, ...res.data.booked];
    } else if (
      res.data.hasOwnProperty('booked') &&
      res.data.hasOwnProperty('reminder')
    ) {
      getSlotList = [...res.data.reminder, ...res.data.booked];
    } else if (
      res.data.hasOwnProperty('alley') &&
      res.data.hasOwnProperty('reminder')
    ) {
      getSlotList = [...res.data.alley, ...res.data.booked];
    } else if (res.data.hasOwnProperty('alley')) {
      getSlotList = [...res.data.alley];
    } else if (res.data.hasOwnProperty('reminder')) {
      getSlotList = [...res.data.reminder];
    } else if (res.data.hasOwnProperty('booked')) {
      getSlotList = [...res.data.booked\];
    }

    console.log(
      ' ~ file: ScheduleTab.js:66 ~ handleGetSlotsList ~ getSlotList',
      getSlotList,
    );
```

Comment: What happened to your code? All of your `[]` brackets have become escaped with backslash characters.

Comment: I've removed the extra slash characters, please ensure your code works as written in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For instance like this ...

```
getSlotList = [];
for (let p of ['booked', 'alley', 'reminder']){
  if (res.data.hasOwnProperty[p]) {
    getSlotList.push(...res.data[p]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed your data properties are arrays.

```
const x = [
    ...res.data.alley?? '',
    ...res.data.booked?? '',
    ...res.data.reminder?? ''
]
```

Be sure you are using a ECMA version compatible with nullish operator [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing)

i have built a little example : [Example](https://playcode.io/1048603)

Comment: This will add empty strings to the result if the property doesn't exist, which is not what the code in the question does. It will also cause an error if the property is undefined instead of an empty array. Try instead `[ ...(res.data.alley || []),` etc.

Comment: @Abe No it won't do neither of the things you claimed because the `??` has a [stronger precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#table)   than `...`  *(3 vs 2)* Thus, `...res.data.alley??''` is equivalent to `...(res.data.alley?? '')` and `[...'']` (what will happen if `res.data.foo` does not exist or is `undefined` or `null`) is an empty array `[]`

Comment: forgot you can spread strings like arrays!  thanks

Comment: @Abe see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o6jm9s13/) which has all possibilities. And there are no empty strings in the result, no errors thrown ... (Yes, jsfiddle can't deal with `??` and `...` in the editor and indicates linter errors, but the code runs fine ...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps by using [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)?

```js
const spread_if_there = (object, keys) =>
  keys.flatMap((key) => object.hasOwnProperty(key) ? object[key] : []);

const data = { alley: [1, 2, 3], reminder: [7, 8, 9] };
const result = spread_if_there(data, ['alley', 'booked', 'reminder']);

console.log( result.join(', ') );
```